# Using confirmation box with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I need to have a confirmation box included before the deletion occurs. I researched this all through here and google and couldn't find a viable option so I'm hoping someone can teach me the right way to approach this.

Function that displays a Delete button within a table in bootstrap...

```
  function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [

      '<a class="remove" onclick="" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">',
      '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
      '</a>',

      '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">',
      '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
      '</a>'
    ].join('')
  }
```

deleteVendor.php

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Include the database connection file (remember to change the connection parameters) */
require './db_inc.php';

/* Include the Account class file */
require './account_class.php';
/* Create a new Account object */
$account = new Account();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$login = FALSE;
$id = $account->getIdFromName($user);
$vendor_id = $_GET['vendor_id'];
try
{
    $login = $account->sessionLogin();



}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

if ($login)
{
}
else
{
    header('Location: ./index.php');
} 


        $query = "DELETE FROM vendors.vendor_data WHERE id=$vendor_id";

        /* Execute the query */
        try
        {
            $res = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $res->execute();


        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
           /* If there is a PDO exception, throw a standard exception */
           throw new Exception($e);
        }


?>
```

Comment: Looking for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 0):

you can use [confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) function for this.

```html
<a href="delete.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Click To Delete</a>
```

Comment: How the delete function is designed doesn't allow me to for some reason. Everytime I try it it crashes the code.

Comment: what you mean by delete function?

Comment: The operateFormatter for my table (see code above). Whenever I try to add your code, or anyones that is simliar, it crashes the table.

Comment: can i see you code? when u add onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"

Comment: ```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [

      '<a class="remove" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">',
      '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
      '</a>',
 
      '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">',
      '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
      '</a>'
    ].join('')
  }
```

Comment: @CodedUnknown What do you mean by "crashes the code" and "crashes the table"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Developer tools says "Unexpected identifier" (forgot to check there) but what I meant was that the table didn't show up anymore after using that code.

Comment: `code`
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) { 
        return [ 
            '<a class="remove" onclick="return confirm(' + "Are you sure?" + ')" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">', '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', '</a>', '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">', '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', '</a>' 
        ].join('');
    }

Comment: or you can use \' inside confirm like this
`code` 
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) { 
        return [ 
            '<a class="remove" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')" href="deleteVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="Remove">', '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', '</a>', '<a class="view" href="viewVendor.php?vendor_id=' + row.id + '" title="View">', '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', '</a>'
        ].join('')
    }

Comment: The table appears now but the confirm box doesn't appear, it goes directly to the deleteVendor.php